# String variable clears after loading another form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two forms, create order and display order. Once the confirm order button has been pressed on CO form, the products are stored into a string variable

```
productsPlaced = Convert.ToString(textBox1.Text + Environment.NewLine + textBox2.Text);
```

Upon confirming the order, console.writeline shows the data still in the variable. 
Upon opening DO form the variable clears and console.writeline shows nothing.

I am trying to display this variable data into another textbox on a different form.

```
textBox1.Text = createOrder.productsPlaced;
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: You don't have to make use of Convert.ToString, you could make the assignment as productsPlaced = textBox1.Text + Environment.NewLine + textBox2.Text

Comment: How are you accessing that string variable on other form? Post that code.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could Declare a Static variable in Form

```
 public static string productsPlaced = null;
 productsPlaced = textBox1.Text + Environment.NewLine + textBox2.Text;
```

In 2nd Form:

```
 tBox1.Text = createOrder.productsPlaced;
```

Comment: Not working either, can't seem to use the variable when it is static

Comment: "can't seem to use the variable when it is static" really?

Comment: Yeah cannot find it when on the 2nd form

Comment: Sorry guys I was being silly, I had to change the createOrder to the actual form name itself.

Comment: Your trying to use the static `productsPlaced` field on a reference to the class. You must use the static class call;